# My search function in C++ is pulling up all the answers and not a single one

Tags: c++, arrays, search

I'm really confused. I have to make this lab for a class and I can't seem to have the search only display one result but all of the months of the year. I also can't seem to figure out why its not displaying the TotalRainfall when I input 0 into the month of the year. 
Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

const int MaxSize = 12; //How many weather lines will be available.

using namespace std;

struct WeatherInformation
{
    int Month;                            //Months of the year
    float TotalMonthsRainfall;            //Total amount of rainfall
    float HighTemp;                       //The Highest temperature of the month.
    float LowTemp;                        //The Lowest temperature of the month.
    float AverageTemp;                    //The Average temperature of the month.
};

WeatherInformation WeatherArray[MaxSize]; //Declaring a month array of MaxSize

void ReadFile(ifstream& MyinFile, WeatherInformation WeatherArray[]);
void WeatherMonthSearch (WeatherInformation WeatherArray[]);


int main()
{
    float TotalRainfall = 0;
    int count = 1;          //Counts how many times the for loop goes.
    int MonthOfWeather;     //User input of the month.
    char ProgramRedo;       //User input if they want to reuse the program.
    char exit_char;         //User input to exit the program.
    ifstream MyinFile;      //Variable that uses file.

    ReadFile (MyinFile, WeatherArray);       //Call ReadFile Function
    WeatherMonthSearch (WeatherArray);       //Call WeatherMonthSearch Function

    MyinFile.close(); //Closes file.
}
//Brett Holmes
//4/30/2013
//PreCondition:You need a file labeled weather.dat
//PostCondition: It puts the file variables into an array.
void ReadFile(ifstream& MyinFile, WeatherInformation WeatherArray[])
{
    float TotalRainfall = 0;
    char exit_char;
    int count = 0;
    int Month = 0;

    cout << "Your Weather Machine" << endl << endl;
    MyinFile.open("weather.dat");
    if (!MyinFile)
    {    //no
        cout << "Can't open input file." << endl; //Tests the right file.
        char exit_char;                         //End Program
        cout << "Press any key to exit" << endl;
        cin >> exit_char;
    }
    for(count = 1; count < MaxSize; count++) //Puts the file variables in the array.
    {
        WeatherArray[count].Month = WeatherArray[count].Month + 1;
        MyinFile >> WeatherArray[count].TotalMonthsRainfall;
        MyinFile >> WeatherArray[count].HighTemp;
        MyinFile >> WeatherArray[count].LowTemp;
        (WeatherArray[count].AverageTemp = ((WeatherArray[count].HighTemp + WeatherArray[count].LowTemp)/2));
        (TotalRainfall = TotalRainfall + WeatherArray[count].TotalMonthsRainfall);
    }
}

//Brett Holmes
//4/30/13
//PreCondition:You need to have the months already put into an array in a struct.
//PostCondition:Outputs the rainfall stats the user puts in then asks to run again.
//Outputs a error message if they type in the month wrong.
void WeatherMonthSearch (WeatherInformation WeatherArray[])
{
    float TotalRainfall;
    int months;
    int MonthOfWeather;
    char ProgramRedo;
    do
    {
        bool MonthFound = false;

        cout << "Please input the number of the Month. Ex. 1=Jan. 2=Feb. etc \n\n";
        cin >> MonthOfWeather;

        for(int i = 1; i <= MaxSize; i++)
        {
            months = WeatherArray[i].Month;
            if(months == MonthOfWeather ) //Finds the artist and outputs the results
            {
                cout << "\nTotal Months Rainfall: " << WeatherArray[i].TotalMonthsRainfall << "   \n";
                cout << "Highest Temperature: " << WeatherArray[i].HighTemp << "   \n";
                cout << "Lowest Temperature: " << WeatherArray[i].LowTemp << "   \n";
                cout << "Average Temperature: " << WeatherArray[i].AverageTemp << "   \n";
                MonthOfWeather = true;
            }
        }
        if(MonthOfWeather == 0)
        {
            cout << "The total rainfall for the year is: " << TotalRainfall << ".";
        }
        if(MonthFound == false)
        {
            cout << "\nMonth Number error. Month not found. Try again.\n\n";
            MonthOfWeather = false;
        }
        cout << "Would you like to look up another month of weather?\n";
        cout << "Enter a 'Y' if yes and 'N' if no.\n";
        cin >> ProgramRedo;
    }while(ProgramRedo == 'Y');
}
```

Comment: You know you're not populating the first entry in your array, right? And `WeatherMonthSearch` is accessing one-element beyond the array size,  into the land of undefined behavior.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Also NOT using the first element of the array... But MaxSize needs to be 13 to cover an array that uses 1..12.

Comment: ... also, `MonthOfWeather = true;` does not make sense...

Comment: This looks like a very suspicious logic `WeatherArray[count].Month = WeatherArray[count].Month + 1;`, considering that `WeatherArray[...].Month` was not initialized previously. Are you sure they all need to be equal to `1`? Shouldn't it be just `WeatherArray[count].Month = count;`?

Comment: @us2012 Methinks that was supposed to be `MonthFound`, or so it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several obvious problems:

1. Arrays in C++ is 0-based, so your for loop is off-by-one. In your search function, `for(int i = 1; i <= MaxSize; i++)` should be `for(int i = 0; i < MaxSize; i++)`. Similarly, in your read function, `for(count = 1; count < MaxSize; count++)` should be `for(count = 0; count < MaxSize; count++)` (If you want to skip index 0 because you are using it as a signal value, then you should set `MaxSize` to 13 and have the loop start at 1.)
2. Why are you assigning a boolean to `MonthOfWeather`? Do you mean `MonthFound`?
3. You read function is not setting the months correctly. `WeatherArray[count].Month = WeatherArray[count].Month + 1;` should be `WeatherArray[count].Month = count;` if you are using a 1-based loop or `WeatherArray[count].Month = count + 1;` if the loop is 0-based.
4. You calculated your total rainfall in the read function, but the result is stored in a local variable so it's lost when the read is done. Either make TotalRainfall a global variable or do your calculations in your search function.
5. There are a lot of redundant variable definitions: for example, your weather data array is a global so there is no reason to actually pass it around; `exit_char` is declared twice in your read function; the first five lines of your `main()` declared variables that you never used.

Also, your read function does not actually exit the program on failure - it even still attempts to read from the stream and then call your search function! If error-checking is a requirement, you should either have the read function return a boolean and check that the read function succeeded before calling your search function, or simply call `std::exit` after that `cin >> exit_char;`.

Answer (score 0):

So, one problem you have is that you have local variables that appear in multiple places, but appears like you expect them to actually contain the same information.

For example, I see three different `TotalRainFall`. One in `main`, which is just there, not used for anything, one in `ReadFile` which is calculated, and one in `WeatherMonthSearch`, which is not set to anything.

I suspect you want all three of these to actually do something. One way to achieve that would be to remove the local ones in `ReadFile` and `WeatherMonthSearch`, and instead pass in the one from `main` (as a reference into `ReadFile`).

There's also a few places where you use variables without initializing them. Make it a habit to initialize EVERYTHING and EVERYWHERE!

Enable warnings in your compiler - if you have any form or reasonably new compiler (gcc or MS Visual Studio of recent vintage), it should tell you at least some of these things.